# Disable Edit review limits outside of review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

Today I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064766/is-there-a-way-to-make-this-code-more-efficient) which I wanted to edit in order to clean up the formatting and make the title describe what the question was really about. But there was already a suggested edit and, because I'd already hit the 20 review limit, I couldn't make the edit. This wouldn't be a problem, except for the fact that I didn't think the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6288502) was very useful; it fixed a few small grammar issues, but didn't deal with the poorly formatted code or useless title.

I propose that the limits on edit reviews only apply to the review queue itself, and that suggested edits which are reached from the question page should still be reviewable, or possibly have a higher limit on them. In order to limit potential abuse, these reviews could not count towards badges, so there's less incentive for people to go hunting for edits to review.

This would give people who have earned editing privileges the freedom to make improvements in these situations without having to wait for the edit to be reviewed, and wouldn't significantly increase the potential for abuse.

Edit:
As was pointed out in the comments, this is actually already mostly possible. I think it should be more prominently displayed when the edit button is clicked, giving a link to reject and edit.

Comment: By the way, if you don't think that the suggested edit is useful, edit the post (`/posts/{id}/edit`), so as the suggested edit will be rejected by Community as conflicting with subsequent edit.

Comment: @nicael okay, thanks. I didn't realize that was an option. I'll modify the feature request.

Comment: Duplicates from Big Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164381/editing-a-post-with-a-pending-edit-after-already-reviewing-20-edits and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193299/i-should-be-able-to-review-suggested-edits-to-my-own-posts-even-if-ive-hit-the